# Ubuntu keeps freezing

Tags: freeze, performance

My laptop has an SSD and 16gb of RAM, so I know the problem isn’t specs.

This laptop used to have Windows and I never ever had any performance issues with it, but this changed ever since I switched to Ubuntu.

I did it because I work with Docker and it runs faster on linux.

The problem is, sometimes the system just completely freezes and I have to wait several minutes for it to work again. There are times it takes so long it’s faster to reboot it with the power button.

Does anyone has any idea of what may be causing this? It happens at least 3 times a day and I am pissed.

I usually use docker, firefox, discord and vscode at the same time. I used all this on Windows too and never had any problems (expect for the fact that docker works much better on linux).

Any insights?

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the Terminal output of `free -m`? Based on what you've said in your question, the results of this command may provide the answer 

Comment: maybe we can assess your hardware with the output of **sudo lshw -short**

Comment: Look at the logs leading up to the freeze `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e`. If there are no hints there, suspect overheating.  Check your fan, check for dust inside your computer. Dust is a good insulator and keeps heat in.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `swapon -s` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: I know this may sound crappy, but did you verify the ISO you downloaded, did you verify the installation media before installing? I have been caught too many times with it before when I get hanging / freezing issues. Also check your temps, in some laptops the fans never spin up in Linux, but just idle. Docker has a way of heating a CPU up. I will assume you checked to see if some docker process or pod is not hanging up the biz? Are you using Ubuntu server or minimal? Did you get anything in the logs?

Answer (score 0):

I report seeing the same problem on an older laptop with an SSD and only 3gb RAM. I have watched RAM and swap usage and I temporarily boosted the RAM with no affect on the problem. I had Docker with Portainer running but doing nothing. The freeze would occur very soon into any Firefox or Vivaldi session but not in a Dillo session. The freeze would also occur in Thunderbird at the point where Thunderbird might be reaching to the web.

When the freeze starts to happen, the browser and most desktop operations are unresponsive, but the mouse still moves the pointer. The keyboard eventually goes dead over time. For example the caps lock light works up until some point. Every now and then there are short instances of life until another freeze, like a unresponsive popup message. If I am fast enough, and prepared, I could switch to a TTY mode and kill the browser in HTOP. Life returns after that. The entire system eventually becomes unresponsive if I do nothing. It does not matter if it is Ubuntu or Kubuntu desktops. I am running Kubuntu 22 now with "nomodeset" and no Docker. This is an older laptop. The "nomodeset" has made other improvements. So far there have been no freezes with Docker not running, (I would never have been able to post this.), but I have yet to start it. I would like more troubleshooting information and also more time without freezes in this current condition before plunging back into running with Docker again. In all my tests I have run only a browser and have paid attention to RAM usage. I also boosted the available swap space to no affect.

I have looked at different logs without noticing anything. One, I am not sure I would spot anything and second, I wonder if the freeze prevents logging. I have tried many times to SSH to the laptop when it freezes. There is always no evidence the laptop is LAN connected.

I do not recall if there was excess heat or fans running or even an over warm feel after letting the laptop sit. I would say it was more likely stone cold.

I have the same model, repurposed laptop running Ubuntu 20.4 full time on Docker tasks. I never saw this problem with it. The only physical difference between the two, other than RAM, is no battery in this one with the issues. I cannot remember if I tested it with the other laptop's battery being used.

I see many instances of this type of problem, i.e. freeze in browser or email application, being reported online. Some go way back in time. I never see any definite explanation as to what is going on or what to specifically diagnostically check for. I think my post could be helpful. My personal experience with this issue ought to be of some help. It contrasts with what Ask Ubuntu says should be in "an answer". I suppose I should apologize for such an opinion.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).